# With a magic item that has no overall restrictions, but special bonuses when used by a certain race, can a L13 Rogue gain that bonus?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, rogue

Imagine a homebrew weapon, for example, a dagger that behaves like a normal +1 dagger to everyone except elves, who are conferred an additional bonus as well other abilities or effects. For this weapon, there are no other properties which impose restrictions on use or benefits.

When a rogue uses any given magic device, how does this work?  Is the rogue effectively "emulating" a certain combination of race/class/level, in order to coax magic out of the device?  Or is the rogue simply ignoring or bypassing restrictions to use a magic device?

In the specific case of the above dagger, the weapon has no requirements that prevent anyone from using it.  However, if the rogue is effectively presenting itself as an elf to the weapon, it might expect to get the bonus.  Given that the description of UMD doesn't really address this specifically, how does this rule?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110880/discussion-on-question-by-doug-stevenson-with-a-magic-item-that-has-no-overall-r).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Moonblade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/moonblade) is an existing example. The Moonblade states that it "(requires attunement by a Elf or Half-Elf of Neutral Good Alignment)" - this is the kind of restriction that the Rogue can ignore.

The kind of wording that would not be affected is wording within the text such as "If an elf wields the weapon, they get +1 to hit", since that wording is not to do with "using" the item.

Here is an example of an item where the Rogue could not use the effect:

> **Elven Dagger**
>
> *Weapon (dagger), uncommon*
>
> You have a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon. When wielded by a Elf, the dagger scores a critical on a roll of 19 or 20.

[Berserk's Axe](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/berserker-axe) is a good example if you want the rogue to be able to use the effect:

> **Elven Dagger**
>
> *Weapon (dagger), uncommon (requires attunement by a Elf)*
>
> You gain a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon. In addition, while you are attuned to this weapon, the dagger scores a critical on a roll of 19 or 20.

Depending on what you want the outcome of your homebrew item to be, you could use similar wording.

Comment: Very helpful to see specific examples.  Thanks, this will help us clarify the currently-unclear definition of the weapon.

Comment: Is wielded by an elf a requirement that applies on use of the weapon? I believe that this answer is categorically wrong due to the narrow definition of "use". In plain English, use means to put something such as a tool, skill, or building to a particular purpose: such as attacking with a weapon - the requirement "Is wielded by an elf" thus is circumvented, and the bonus applies.

If the rogue's class feature said on equipment/attunement, then your answer would be correct.

Comment: Or if that is more accessible if "is wielded by an elf" was not a requirement to attain a bonus on use, you may as well ignore the text as it is deprived of meaning, and no condition qualifies for fulfilment due to nothing being required.

Comment: @Akixkisu It is not required to use the item, therefore it is not a "requirement on use".

Comment: @gszavae ah there is where your misunderstanding comes from, it is "You ignore all class, race, and level requirements on the use of Magic Items." - so you ignore ***all*** requirements when you use the item (such as whacking someone's face with said item). It is not "you ignore all requirments to attune/equip the item." Emphasis on "on the use" not "requirements to use" (use is a much broader definition in plain English that also includes equipment and attunement).

Comment: @Akixkisu It's not "On use, you ignore all requirements", it's "you ignore all requirements on the use". If it's not a "requirement on the use", you don't get to ignore it. "Requirements on the use" means that the requirements must be met in order to use the item! In the case of "you get a bonus if you are an elf" that is not a requirement on the use of the item, since you can use the item without meeting it.

Answer (score 3):

## It's Unclear

Here's the text of the rogue Use Magic Device ability:

> You ignore all class, race, and level requirements on the use of Magic Items.

If a weapon gives extra bonuses to elves, is that a "race requirement", or merely a bonus specific to that race?  We don't know!

There aren't any rules about what counts as a race requirement and what doesn't.

## Your DM Decides

We're not an official rules source, and we're not allowed to issue rulings.  When the rules are ambiguous, as happens *frequently* in D&D 5e, it's your DM's job to tell you what happens.

That's especially true for homebrew stuff.

It would be wrong for us to try to tell anyone how to resolve this issue, because someone might go to their DM and say: "your homebrew has to work in this way because the people on this website said so!"

Ask your DM.

Answer (score -2):

> By 13th level, you have learned enough about the workings of magic that you can improvise the use of items even when they are not intended for you. **You ignore all class, race, and level requirements on the use of Magic Items.**

This seems quite clear to me. All restrictions to the use of the magic item are removed so the Rogue uses it as if they are an Elf i.e. get the full benefits.

Mechanically, the Rogue isn't emulating the required class/level/race restrictions of the item. They are simply irrelevant when the magic item is being used by the Rogue.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110838/discussion-on-answer-by-steve-with-a-magic-item-that-has-no-overall-restrictions).

Answer (score -3):

#### Homebrew is fundamentally problematic for published rule adjudication.

It's 100% possible that your DM has specifically designed the dagger in some way that overrides any and all published information. Check with your DM for a definitive answer.

However, taking your description as entirely true, it's the latter: the Rogue ignores the restrictions.

The text of *Use Magic Device* says that

> **Use Magic Device**
>
> By 13th level, you have learned enough about the workings of magic that you can improvise the use of items even when they are not intended for you. You ignore all class, race, and level requirements on the use of magic items.

*You ignore all class, race, and level requirements* strongly suggests that the restrictions are bypassed, not faked (though there's room in the description for the bypassing to be *due to* some sort of magical imitation, if you prefer).

So, lore-wise, the Rogue knows enough about how magic works that they can use any magic item by interacting with the magic directly.

In the specific case of the homebrewed dagger, I don't see any reason that bypassing this magical requirement would be different. The Rogue doesn't need to present themselves as an elf, they simply cause the magic in the dagger to behave as it would for an elf.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110837/discussion-on-answer-by-upper-case-with-a-magic-item-that-has-no-overall-restric).

Comment: Essentially I agree with your answer, but I think it could be better argued, see https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/172285/with-a-magic-item-that-has-no-overall-restrictions-but-special-bonuses-when-use#comment462566_172291 for reference.